# Permission error in virtual machine manager

Tags: permissions, kvm-virtualization, virt-manager

I am trying to install win8.1 as a guest on my Ubuntu 14.04 using KVM and virt manager. When I choose the path of the ISO file in virt manager, it throws this error:

> The emulator may not have search permissions for the path '`/media/owerfoll/B/windows8.1 Enterprise.iso'`

How I can fix this?!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I had the same issue as well. I fixed it by doing the following:

1. Run `virt-manager` with `sudo`:

```
        sudo virt-manager
```

2. Attempt to create your VM. When the error dialog appears, click *Yes* to correct the error.

   What this does is change the user and group of your image file (to `libvirt-qemu:libvirt-qemu` if that's your `virt-manager` user). You could also `sudo chown libvirt-qemu:libvirt-qemu <image-file>` if you want to do it manually.
3. When you get to the next step, cancel the creation process and close `virt-manager`.
4. Now relaunch `virt-manager` without `sudo` and attempt to create your VM again.

Comment: It just changes the file to `root:root`, definitely not what one would want. But the workaround works though.

Comment: `sudo virt-manager` doesn't seem to launch:  `(virt-manager:6118): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0
`

Answer (score 8):

Just encountered this setting up a VM. Pressing the <kbd>Yes</kbd> button to automatically fix the problem sets extended ACLs on the file. You can see this by running an ls -l on your directory, and checking the permissions for other.

Instead of opening up permissions for all users in other, you can explicitly set them using `setfacl`

From the man page:

```
EXAMPLES
   Granting an additional user read access
          setfacl -m u:lisa:r file
```

Since I wanted to grant the `libvirt-qemu` user execute rights to install my vm, I ran:

```
    setfacl -m u:libvirt-qemu:x
```

This sets permissions for specific users, without changing the execute bit for an entire group of the directory. I'm a fan of the tighter control. The permissions on the file should read something like `-rw-rw-r-+`, with the `+` meaning there are extended permissions set.

You could just press the <kbd>Yes</kbd> button and not worry about what it's doing, but I chose to check it out. I was then able to continue setup in virt-manager without running with `sudo` and without further error.

Answer (score 4):

Just wanted to toss in my problem/solution in case it helps anyone.  I was letting the OS (GalliumOS in my case) decide how and where to mount my external USB SSD where my virtual machine is stored.

It was mounting to `/media/<me>/MySSD` by default.

I installed `gnome-disk-utility`, and went in and reconfigured the mount options for that USB drive.  I unchecked "use system defaults" and let gnome disks fill in the rest of the settings by itself, which change my mount point to /dev/

Then virt-manager no longer had any issues accessing my gcow file

You can do it manually in /etc/fstab, this was just faster for me.